# Change the Calendar to this week plus five

Tags: view, sharepoint-calendar

Not sure if this is possible, but I would like to change the calendar to display this week and the next five weeks instead of just the month.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is nothing OOTB to do that. You will need to code in a Calendar's view in order to achieve that.

If I were you, I would add a CEWP with some JavaScript that would duplicate last calendar week, and change corresponding events. Or create a custom webpart from zero.